# How to remove lines based on another file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Now I have two files as follows:

```
$ cat file1.txt
john  12  65  0
Nico  3   5   1
king  9   5   2
lee   9   15  0

$ cat file2.txt
Nico
king
```

Now I would like to remove each line which contains a name fron the second file in its first column.

Ideal result:

```
john  12  65  0
lee   9   15  0
```

Could anyone tell me how to do that? I have tried the code like this:

```
for i in 'less file2.txt'; do sed "/$i/d" file1.txt; done
```

But it does not work properly.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This job suites `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file2.txt file1.txt
```

```
john  12  65  0
lee   9   15  0
```

**Details:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file
  a[$1]                      # store the first field in an array a
  next                       # move to next line  
}
!($1 in a)                   # while processing the second file
                             # if first field doesn't exist in array a then print
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot : ) I will accept it as the answer. Could you explain a little bit about your code? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to iterate it, you just need to use grep with`-v` option to invert match and `-w` to force pattern to match only WHOLE words

```
grep -wvf file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: This will give incorrect result as it may match partial words. e.g. if first file has a name starting with `kingsley` then this command will not display that as well.

Comment: That can be mitigated with the `-w` option. And might want to add `-F` as well.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for pointing that out, with -w option we can fix this as glenn said. updated the answer